# Empty or Null value display in SSRS text boxes

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Using SSRS (2008) what is the best way you have found to handle null or empty values and replace them with something else to display. The quite obvious solutions is

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value),"NA",Fields!MyFields.Value)
```

That works though it is tedious, my hope was to find something like an EmptyText property on the textbox but alas nothing. Any ideas? Should I make a custom report item from the TextBox base that creates this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call a custom function?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798.aspx

You could always put a case statement in there to handle different types of 'blank' data.

Comment: Choosing this answer because most others deal with ISNULL in sql and that is not an SSRS specific solution. Valid solution but the problem scope here it limited to SSRS.

Answer (score 12):

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(CStr(Fields!MyFields.Value)) or CStr(Fields!MyFields.Value) = "","-",CStr(Fields!MyFields.Value))
```

Use this expression you may get the answer.

Here CStr is an default function for handling String datatypes.

Answer (score 6):

I would disagree with converting it on the server side.  If you do that it's going to come back as a string type rather than a date type with all that entails (it will sort as a string for example)

My principle when dealing with dates is to keep them typed as a date for as long as you possibly can.

If your facing a performance bottleneck on the report server there are better ways to handle it than compromising your logic.

Comment: I agree with this approach.  It makes sense to get the data from the server structured and typed correctly, then decide how to present it in the reporting layer.

Answer (score 2):

While probably not any better than your solution, you could adjust your T-SQL to return the same result using COALESCE:

```
SELECT MyField = COALESCE(table.MyField, " NA")
```

The reasoning for the extra space before the NA is to allow sorting to place the NA results at the top.  Since your data may vary, that may not be a great option.

Comment: This is not always viable. In the case of a `MATRIX`, you may have a `PIVOT` scenario that results in "holes" in your fields because you `INNER JOIN`ed in your SQL and `LEFT JOIN` would result in a cost penalty.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on performing the replace on the SQL side, but using the ISNULL function would be the way I'd go.

```
SELECT ISNULL(table.MyField, "NA") AS MyField
```

I usually do as much processing of data on our SQL servers and try to do as little data manipulation in SSRS as possible. This is mainly because my SQL server is considerably more powerful than my SSRS server.

Comment: I tend to favour `COALESCE` over `IsNull` simply because I work with both Oracle and SQL Server and `COALESCE` works with both.

Answer (score 0):

Either in SQL or in report code (as per adolf garlic's function suggestion)

At this moment in time, I'd do it in the report. I have very few reports against a busy OLTP server and an underwhelmed report server. If I had a different mix I'd do it in SQL.

Either way is acceptable...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `IsNothing()` to behave and I didn't want to create dummy rows in my `dataset` (e.g. for a given list of customers create a dummy order per month displayed) and noticed that null values were displaying as -247192.

Lo and behold using that worked to suppress it (at least until MSFT changes SSRS for the better from 08R2) so forgive me but:

```
=iif(Fields!Sales_Diff.Value = -247192,"",Fields!Sales_Diff.Value)
```

Comment: The only conceivable reason for nulls displaying this way is if you had an expression somewhere that didn't account for them properly and returned bizarre results when they occurred, in which case it would be your problem and not Microsoft's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!MyField.Value)=TRUE,"NA",Fields!MyFields.Value)
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar situation but the following worked best for me..

```
=Iif(Fields!Sales_Diff.Value)>1,Fields!Sales_Diff.Value),"")
```